# Batch to keep only certain characters in a string

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file, trim

I have a variable coming from a `for` loop in a batch file :

```
for /f Tokens^=3^,10delims^=^<^>^" %%i in ('findstr -i "href=" bookmarks.html') do (
   set str1=%%j
```

How to keep only certain characters in the variable `str1` ?   : a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Example :
`Blabla</2378:.,`         =>       `Blabla2378`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a solution with : Replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` by `""`?
How to do a search/replace regexp with BATCH?

Comment: There is no "replace" tool in batch, but you can use `sed` for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "string=+"
FOR /l %%i IN (32,1,127) DO CALL :addstring %%i
ECHO !string!
FOR /l %%i IN (100,-1,0) DO CALL :delstring %%i
ECHO !string!
GOTO :eof

:addstring
CALL CMD /c EXIT /b %1
SET "string=!string!!=exitcodeascii!"
GOTO :eof

:delstring
SET cp=!string:~%1!
IF NOT DEFINED cp GOTO :EOF 
ECHO abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|FIND "!string:~%1,1!" >NUL 2>nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :eof
SET /a cp=%1+1
SET "string=!string:~0,%1!!string:~%cp%!"
GOTO :eof
```

Well - here's a way to do at least a great deal of it.

The `ADDSTRING` routine simply builds a list of characters, with a "+" at the beginning for no reason other than demonstrating the string starts with a space.

By calling `delstring` repeatedly, running backwards from the end of the string, each character that isn't in the alphamerics list is removed.

---

edit to apply example strings

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "string=+-=++()*&^^^#!!!<--remove all of those and those----->.,?/';][}{__"
ECHO before: !string!
FOR /l %%i IN (70,-1,0) DO CALL :delstring %%i
ECHO after : !string!
SET "string= "blablabla23:/./é'""
ECHO before: !string!
FOR /l %%i IN (20,-1,0) DO CALL :delstring %%i
ECHO after : !string!
GOTO :eof

:delstring
SET cp=!string:~%1!
IF NOT DEFINED cp GOTO :EOF 
ECHO abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|FIND "!string:~%1,1!" >NUL 2>nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :eof
SET /a cp=%1+1
SET "string=!string:~0,%1!!string:~%cp%!"
GOTO :eof
```

A caution to OP: the syntax `SET string = "something"` **IS** sensitive to the presence of spaces. It sets the value of the variable `"string "` - not of `"string"` - the space is INCLUDED in the variable name. Equally, the leading space and the double-quotes ARE included in the value assigned.

The syntax `set "var=value"` is designed to ensure any trailing spaces on the line are NOT included in the value assigned to the variable `var`. Note that this syntax DOES allow double-quotes within the assigned string.

---

Further methods

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET str1="blabla"
SET "allowedchars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

ECHO before: !str1!
FOR /l %%i IN (70,-1,0) DO CALL :delstr1 %%i
ECHO after : !str1!
SET "str1= "blablabla23:/./é'""
ECHO before: !str1!
FOR /l %%i IN (20,-1,0) DO CALL :delstr1 %%i
ECHO after : !str1!

ECHO ============================ now let's try that again.
ENDLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET str1="blabla"
SET "allowedchars=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

ECHO before: !str1!
CALL :delstr2 str1
ECHO after : !str1!
SET "str1= "blablabla23:/./é'""
ECHO before: !str1!
CALL :delstr2 str1
ECHO after : !str1!



GOTO :eof

:delstr1
SET cp=!str1:~%1!
IF NOT DEFINED cp GOTO :EOF 
ECHO !allowedchars!|FIND "!str1:~%1,1!" >NUL 2>nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :eof
SET /a cp=%1+1
SET "str1=!str1:~0,%1!!str1:~%cp%!"
GOTO :eof

:delstr2
SETLOCAL
SET cp=0
:delstr2a
SET "$_=!%1:~%cp%!"
IF DEFINED $_ SET /a cp+=1&GOTO delstr2a
SET "$_=!%1!"
:delstr2b
IF NOT DEFINED %1 GOTO delstr2done
SET /a cp-=1
IF %cp% lss 0 GOTO delstr2done
ECHO !allowedchars!|FIND "!$_:~%cp%,1!" >NUL 2>NUL
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO delstr2b
SET /a ca=cp+1
SET "$_=!$_:~0,%cp%!!$_:~%ca%!"
GOTO delstr2b
:delstr2done 
endlocal&SET "%1=%$_%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Batch is extraordinarily slow. It CAN do the job, it's just going to take its time about it. I mean I CAN mow the grass in my backyard, too - I just take my time about it.

Now if you want to do the job on thousands of strings, presumably they're in one or more files. You should locate SED - Googling `GNU SED` would be a good start.

A SED line to do what you have asked would be

```
sed s/[^^a-zA-Z0-9]//g <filename >newfilename
```

where the double-caret is required because caret is a special character as far as `CMD.EXE` is concerned and hence it needs to be escaped by a caret.

Comment: thanks a lot peter!
but i'm a little bit lost (i don't undertand these `call cmd` etc.) do you have an example with a simple example string?
example : `mystr1 = "blablabla23:/./é'"`

Comment: All the `addstring` routine is doing is to build a string of printable characters. It isn't involved with the 'remove all non-alphameric' function. All you need to do is assign whatever string you from which want to select-out non-alphamerics, then execute the `FOR /l...:delstring %%i` command with the first of the three numbers in the parentheses being at least the length of the string `string`. 8000 is a good number - but the larger it is, the longer the routine will take to run. I'll amend the post with a few examples.

Comment: thanks but I'm still lost... would you have an example beginning with 

    `@ECHO OFF`
    `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` 
    `SET str1="blabla"`
    `SET allowedchars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`

and would end with `echo str2` where `str2` is the cleaned version of `str1` ?

thanks a lot a lot a lot in advance!

Comment: something strange : it takes 1 or 2 seconds per string  (50 character long in average)...
and I have 1000s of string to process ;)